# Missing assembly reference on publishing workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have used Custom actions for SharePoint Designer from the solution in codeplex http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

I have installed the latest wsp and enabled the feature in my site. I have created a sample workflow with the action 'Send email with list item attachments', when publishing the workflow, I am getting the following error,

(0, 10) The type or namespace name 'DP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))
(19, 16) The type or namespace name 'DP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

I have checked, the dll is deployed to GAC and safe controls are registered to Web.config file.

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: i think, it is better if you post your question directly on codeplex project place so that developer can respond it.

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue. did you solve it?

Comment: Hi Saksham , we didn't find the solution and we leave this.